# Java: Possible Loss of Precision When Using `Math.sin()`

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I am new to Java. I want to print out the `sin`, `cos` and `tan` values for every 15 degree interval.

```
public class W3Aufgabe5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.printf("%6s%6s%6s%6s%n", "Angle", "Sin", "Cos", "Tan");
        System.out.println("------------------------");

        for (float angle = 0; angle <= 180; angle += 15) {

            float sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
            float cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
            float tan = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(angle));

            System.out.printf("%6d%6d%6d%6d%n", angle, sin, cos, tan);
        }
    }
}
```

For every `Math.x()` line, the compiler prints

> error: possible loss of precision
>       required: float
>       found: double

I don't really understand. Why does it require `double` even though I am using `float` all the time?

Comment: Why do you have float sin? Just use double unless you have an actual reason to use float, eg. image manipulation, or graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigonometric methods [`sin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin-double-), `cos`, [`tan`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#tan-double-), and [`toRadians`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) all accept `double` as a parameter and return `double`.  There are no overloads that accept `float`s and return `float`s.  It's legal to pass a `float` to a method expecting a `double`; it will be widened implicitly.  But you can't narrow a `double` to a `float` implicitly when you assign the results to `float`s.

You can explicitly cast the results to `float` if you want, but you get better precision with `double`, so declare your `sin`, `cos`, and `tan` variables as `double`s.

Also, the format specifier `d` means integer values, not floating point values.  Use the [format specifier `f` instead of `d`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).  You may also want to place some spacing in between your values when you print them.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I thought the format specifiers `f` and `d` had something to do with float and double

Comment: No, `f` stands for "fixed-point" (as format), `e` for exponential or engineering and `g` selects the most appropriate. See the C printf format strings that were also the basis for the Java printf function.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), you will see that the trig methods will all return doubles. Unless you really need a float, your best bet would be to use doubles instead. You lose precision because you have to force your double return values into floats.